# Создание виртуальных com-портов в Debian для VirtualBox

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, serial, com-port

Имеется хост система с Debian-ом, в virtualbox заведены две виртуальные машины: с windows7 и Астра-линуксом. Обе виртуалки содеражат приложения общающиеся через com-порт. Как создать виртуальную пару com-портов и передать их виртуальным машинам для установления связи? Подскажите решение или направление куда копать.

Answer (score 2):

Подразумевая, что нужно создать обычноее нуль-модемное соединение между двумя виртуальными машинами, это можно сделать средствами VirtualBox'а: перенаправить порты обеих машин на один сокет, обычный UNIX-домена (в коробке зовётся по-виндовому «*хост-каналом*») или tcp, при этом в настройках одной из них надо задать, чтобы она подключалась к существующему сокету, а во второй — нет...

Пример настроек:

[image: Пример настроек]

Со второй машиной всё точно также, но снять галочку. Первой должна запускаться машина без галочки.

Аналогично можно использовать и сетевые сокеты, например `localhost:5151`.